# Snake game: fast response vs. collision bug

Tags: c++, sfml, keyboard-events

I have a snake game in SFML C++, and I'm stuck between two options.  If set the controls like this:

```
    if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up
            || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::W) && move != Down)
        move = Up;

    else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down
            || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S) && move != Up)
        move = Down;

    else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left
            || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)&& move != Right)
        move = Left;

    else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right
            || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D) && move != Left)
        move = Right;
```

Here, the controls are very responsive. The problem is that if, for instance, the snake were going rightward and you were to press Up and then Left in extremely quick succession, the snake will not have moved upward yet, but the upward control will be buffered so the snake will be allowed to move leftward into itself, thus dying.

If instead I wrap these movement conditions in an if statement that only allows updating once per frame the bug is resolved, but the controls are much less smooth and responsive.

So my question is, how do I maintain the responsiveness of allowing the movement to update quickly while avoiding the bug of moving into itself?

Comment: Well, what should happen, according to you? Presumably, the snake is not moving with infinite speed so you can only allow directional changes after your snake is done doing its current move.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write it, but I basically want it to work so that if I press Up and then Left very quickly, it will move up on the next snake movement, then save the left command for the following snake movement instead of disregarding it if the elapsed time synced with the frame rate hasn't been reached.

Comment: Then that's already your solution isn't it? Just save a list of inputs and read from that whenever you need to do your next move

Comment: So instead of having only `enum Direction {Up, Down, Left, Right};` I should also keep track of the previous direction? Ok I think that makes sense. I'll try implementing it, thanks.

Comment: You can always append a keystroke to a queue, and execute that queue in a timer

Comment: Haven't seen that before, but that might be what I'm looking for. Can max size of the queue be set if I don't want more than 2 keystrokes to get queued?

Comment: You can make a wrapper around a container in order to provide that behaviour if you want, or you can just check its size() member function before you append: if the current size() == MAX_CAPACITY, ignore input; else append to queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that your making Snake; The problem lies not with your input(but those "if's" should be a switch statement)  but within the Object that reacts with the input, ex. the "Snake_Object". The normal game forces a set number of positional movement when a direction is pressed. If you watch the game, if you press up then the snake is immediately forced up one collision box above where it was from before. This insures that you can not do your unwanted immediate collision and still keeps regular fps flow.

So when the move variable is sent to the Snake it should in the very first instance move a whole collision box in that direction and then move at normal speed.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this is what was happening in the original snake game. I'll try to implement this soon. For now I came up with a temporary solution  of removing the input choices from the timing loop, but making them control a second move variable instead. Then I set the first move variable equal to the second within the timing/movement loop.  This makes it responsive without bugging out for now, but I would like to try it the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience in game development, and I am not even sure I understand your question.

However, I wonder if the following structure for your code would help controlling the update process:

```
inline void UpdateMoveUp(Move& move)      { if(move != Down)  { move = Up;    }}
inline void UpdateMoveDown(Move& move)    { if(move != Up)    { move = Down;  }}
inline void UpdateMoveLeft(Move& move)    { if(move != Right) { move = Left;  }}
inline void UpdateMoveRight(Move& move)   { if(move != Left)  { move = Right; }}
inline void UpdateMoveInvalid(Move& move) { move = Invalid; }

inline void HandleUpdate(const Code& code, Move& move) {

  switch(code) {

    case sf::Keyboard::Up:
      return UpdateMoveUp(move);
    case sf::Keyboard::W:
      return UpdateMoveUp(move);

    case sf::Keyboard::Down:
      return UpdateMoveDown(move);
    case sf::Keyboard::S:
      return UpdateMoveDown(move);

    case sf::Keyboard::Left:
      return UpdateMoveLeft(move);
    case sf::Keyboard::A:
      return UpdateMoveLeft(move);

    case sf::Keyboard::Right:
      return UpdateMoveRight(move);
    case sf::Keyboard::D:
      return UpdateMoveRight(move);

    default:
      return UpdateMoveInvalid(move);
  }
}

void HandleInput(const Event& event, Move& move) {
  // I assume that `move` comes from somewhere else
  if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
    return HandleUpdate(event.key.code, move);
  }
}
```

The way I look at it is that you are isolating the update function to a single place, and you can add more conditions to the update there without having to test the whole condition again.

In other words, you could add further conditions to each `UpdateMoveXXXX` function, such as *unbuffer and update* or *save timestamp and move* (then move only if last timestamp minus current timestamp is more/less than some number).